# An alphanumeric sorting algorithm with scanf c

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, scanf, quicksort

I have created a program that sorts strings in an array in alphanumeric order.

But my question is how to make it so that when you run the program, it asks for the strings (with a `scanf` but the question is how with a `char const *array`?) and then the program sorts and creates a new file in which the result will be saved.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

FILE *myFile = NULL;
static void consoleWrite(char const **a, size_t b) {
    size_t i;
    for (i = 0; i < b; i++)
        fprintf(myFile, "%s ", a[i]);
    printf("\n");
}

static int string_cmp(void const *i, void const *j) {
    char const *const *pointerI = i;
    char const *const *pointerJ = j;   
    return strcmp(*pointerJ, *pointerI); // comparaison de la chaine de caractère !
}

int main(void) {
    char const *array[] = { 
        "01", "fdf", "gffg", "FRSTM-PFOV1DK", "FRSTM-KEFF2OQHT"
    };

    myFile = fopen("file.ini", "a+");
    long array_size = sizeof array / sizeof *array;

    qsort(array, array_size, sizeof *array, string_cmp);
    consoleWrite(array, array_size);
    printf("Le tri a été effectué ! ");

    return 0;
}
```

I would like to save my data in the variable array and then with this variable I sort.

Comment: OT: regarding: `fprintf (myFile, "%s ", a[i]);`  Suggest appending a '\n' to the format string, so each item from the array is on a separate line in the output file.

Comment: OT: regarding: ` myFile =fopen("file.ini", "a+");`  always check (!=NULL) the returned value to assure the operation was successful.  If not successful, then call `perror( "your error message" );  exit( EXIT_FAILURE );`  Note: `exit()` and `EXIT_FAILURE` are exposed via the header file: `stdlib.h`

Comment: regarding: `myFile =fopen("file.ini", "a+");`  Why the `+` in the mode when the file is never being read from?  The `a` in the mode means the file will get bigger every time the program is run.  Is that what you want?

Comment: do you realize the file is being sorted in descending order (due to the order of the parameters in the call to `strcmp()`?

Comment: regarding the statement: `printf ("\n");`  do you realize that the output of the `printf()` statement will go to your terminal and NOT to the file being produced.  Is this what you want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can allocate memory dynamically for this. Asking for first the number of strings the user will enter, then allocating a `char*` array of that size. Then reading in the strings, saving it a buffer, allocating enough memory for the entered string and copy the buffer content to it. Like so

```
int main(void) {
  int array_size = 0;
  char **array;
  char buffer[256];

  myFile = fopen("file.ini", "a+");

  scanf("%d", &array_size);
  array = malloc(array_size * sizeof(char*));

  for(int i = 0; i < array_size; i++) {
    scanf("%s", buffer);
    array[i] = malloc(strlen(buffer) + 1);
    strncpy(array[i], buffer, strlen(buffer) + 1);
  }

  qsort(array, array_size, sizeof *array, string_cmp);
  consoleWrite(array, array_size);
  printf("Le tri a été effectué ! ");

  for(int i = 0; i < array_size; i++)
    free(array[i]);
  free(array);

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: You should protect against potential undefined behavior with `scanf("%249s", buffer);` and test the return values of `scanf()` and `malloc()`.

Comment: `strncpy(array[i], buffer, strlen(buffer) + 1);` produces the same result as `strcpy(array[i], buffer);`. **Don't use `strncpy`, its semantics are widely misunderstood and error prone.**